# How should I migrate a disjoint myriad of click-once applications to a coherent tool suite

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, clickonce, versioning, auto-update

I maintain a set of tools for internal use at our company.
These tools are mostly referencing the same dll's.

These tools are used in different parts of our production, which makes widely different QA procedures applicable to the various tools.

Therefore, some are updated frequently. 
Others are rarely updated and have pretty long and expensive release procedures involving various departments. A user must be able to update tool A with its dependencies without affecting tool B and its dependencies.

For the moment, I have the tools independently deployed as click-once applications. The common dll's are rapdidly changing and this allows the different tools to be deployed with different versions of the dll's. The "check for update" when connected to corporate network is highly appreciated.

However, some user feel that the windows start menu is not the desired top level framework for the apps. There are no descriptions, screen shots, support links or any such candy that present the applications. As the number of tools go up, the naming and handling becomes more and more contrived.

Do anybody have suggestions or opinions? I am currently googling along these lines:

- Does PRISM/MEF or similar support check for update and for two plugins to run against different versions of common dll's?
- Is there any way to programmatically handle .Application files (the stuff that click-once setup.exe deploys on client machines)? Can I load a .Application file and then interrogate it for details (such as checking for update) and/or launch it?
- I would imagine that this form of app-store'ish accommodation will be part of metro, when Microsoft unveils the corporate story. I don't know that I can wait that long, though.

Thoughts?

Comment: Based on your stated user complaints it sounds like you need some sort of dashboard application to bring everything together. It could be a simple as a launcher, or a more complex host application that hosts the existing apps as in-process plugins. The latter is a minefield though and I wouldn't attempt it lightly.

Comment: A launcher would probably be enough. A client that would identify installed apps either from "installed programs" or the windows start menu. This is why I would like to know if I can "manage" (including launching) the .Application files.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit scattered in thought, but I think I understand what you are asking-- can you manage the installation of a ClickOnce application?  The answer is Yes!

Specifically, create a [Custom ClickOnce Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997001.aspx)

From within the installers `GetManifestCompleted` event, you can handle the Manifest (effectively the `.application` file) by accessing and processing the `GetManifestCompletedEventArgs.ApplicationManifest` property (which is an `XMLReader` object.)

Creating your own Custom Installer for your case could be a bit complex.  I recommend reading the article I provided and then brain-storm both what you need and what this information might be able to provide.  This is about the best answer that can be given, at least from the ClickOnce perspective, although, there may be entirely different alternatives using different forms of deployment technology.